# Azure Storage 400 on one WebServer but not dev or local

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Connection to my Azure Storage Account on the Production App Services (WebSite) results in a 400 Error.  Connecting to the same Azure Storage Account from local development box works correctly.
Connection to the same Azure Storage Account from our Development App Service (Website) works correctly.
The production server uses the Azure Key Vault for the connection setting and I have checked the value is being returned.  I have intentionally modified the key vault value to ensure it was being used.

The following throughs a 400 Bad Request Error. There is no Inner Exception Message.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(_configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageConnection").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value);
CloudTableClient tableClients = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
```

Additional information:
I have checked the Overview and the General Settings between the Development App Service and Production App Service.  They match where appropriate.  Something seems to wrong for this App Service.
I have switched the look up from the keyvault to configuration file and that has worked.  The issue seems to be with pulling the key value from the keyvault.  I have compared the value stored in the keyvault to the app configuration to make sure they match.

Exception Returned:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. 
Stack trace1: at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken callerCancellationToken) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`1.<ExecuteSync>b__0() 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.Utils.RestUtility.RunWithoutSynchronizationContext[T](Func`1 actionToRun) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableCommand.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.RestExecutor.TableRestExecutor.ExecuteTableOperation[TResult](TableOperation operation, CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation.Execute(CloudTableClient client, CloudTable table, TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudTable.Create(TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext, String serializedIndexingPolicy, Nullable`1 throughput, Nullable`1 defaultTimeToLive) 
at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.CloudTable.CreateIfNotExists(TableRequestOptions requestOptions, OperationContext operationContext, String serializedIndexingPolicy, Nullable`1 throughput, Nullable`1 defaultTimeToLive) 
at Esperanto.Manager.Services.AzureTableStorageManagement.ReadAllEntity() in /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyCode/AzureTableStorageManagement.cs:line 199
```

Please note originally only one line of code was shown because it was the line mentioned in the stacktrace but it may be the line that is immediately after.  This has been included.

Comment: The above code should not throw 400 error because no network request is made when creating an instance of `CloudStorageAccount`.

Comment: @GauravMantri I updated the question.  The stacktrace was mistaken on the line causing the exception.

Comment: Again, this line also can't throw 400 error :). I believe the error is coming when you're trying to create a table in your code. Most likely your table name is incorrect. Can you share the name of the table you're trying to create. Also, please share the subsequent code as well.

Comment: Basically share relevant code in `AzureTableStorageManagement.cs` (ideal if you can share the entire code otherwise code of `ReadAllEntity()` method as the error is coming from there.

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by rebuilding the azure website. Something was stuck or cached.  Sorry this is not a better answer.